# Access an index of an stdclass object

Tags: php, object, stdclass

I have an stdClass object that looks like this:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 123
            [name] => John Doe
            [date_created] => 13552412
        )
```

Is there a way to access an stdclass object by its index number and not through its name?

Comment: What index number? `[0]` is not part of the `stdClass` object, it's part of the array that the object is a value in.

Comment: Access it as `$array[0]`.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert it to an array with numeric keys:

```
$array = array_values(get_object_vars($obj));
echo $array[1]; // John Doe
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to access its elements with a numerical index?

```
$array = array_values((array) $object);

echo $array[0]; // id
echo $array[1]; // name
echo $array[2]; // date_created
```

I'm not really sure what you mean. If you could elaborate, I can edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

or you can access it like this

```
foreach ($objects as $obj) {
    echo $obj->id;
    echo $obj->name;
    echo $obj->date_created;
}
```